# SSMS rolling count based on value resetting at 0

Tags: sql-server, ssms, gaps-and-islands

Trying to get a rolling count that resets when 0 is hit.

Only need a few fields.

- Ordered by the date field and then ref field
- when value goes 0 to >0 count begins at 1
- If value remains same or increases count goes to 2 and beyond
- if value goes to 0 count goes back to 0
- repeats if value changes to >0 again at 1

Date:

```
Date   Ref    Value   Count
202201 170532 £300.21 1
202202 170532 £600.42 2
202203 170532 £0.00   0
202204 170532 £300.21 1
202205 170532 £600.42 2
202206 170532 £900.63 3
```

..
..

Tried a few things i've read on here but not having much joy.

Thanks for any help or direction provided!

Comment: Your "date" appears to be missing a part, it's only 6 digits long, not 8.

Answer (score 1):

Put your rows into groups first, by `COUNT`ing how many times `0` has been in the dataset prior, and then you can use a `ROW_NUMBER` on that group. You'll need to use couple of `CASE` expressions as well to put `0` in the right place.:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT Date,
           Ref,
           Value,
           COUNT(CASE Value WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(202201,170532,300.21),
                (202202,170532,600.42),
                (202203,170532,0.00  ),
                (202204,170532,300.21),
                (202205,170532,600.42),
                (202206,170532,900.63))V(Date,Ref,Value))
SELECT Date,
       Ref,
       Value,
        CASE Value WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE Value WHEN 0 THEN 0 END, Grp ORDER BY Date ASC) END AS RN
FROM Grps
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```